# Implementing downloadable code and content plugins for Android

Tags: java, android, plugins

I'm kinda new to a plugin development in Java and Android, so I wanted to ask this basic question.

Consider that I have some framework which has some Factory which can produce certain classes - these classes perform some plugin-like functionality. I want to implement a plugin system that would be able to somehow download new plugins from some server and make them available for that Factory for creation.

And the basic requirements for plugin is:

- it contains code by implementing some common *interface*
- it contains *resources* (for example drawables)

For example this might be a "shapes" drawing app. each plugin has code to draw() a shape, optionally by using bitmap for filling that shape - in this case bitmap is supplied with a plugin as a resource.

How should I go about this? Any pointers to google search terms and hints are appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Try reading about PathClassLoader, DexClassLoader and such. I'm not sure if you will be able to use them but these little classes helped me to write object mapper with ease. You will probably have to use annotation (@MyClassOrWhatever) too, to mark classes as plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this on Android, because of security restrictions. It is very likely that your only option is to distribute plugins as separate application in the Market (like Doplhin browser does).

However, the problem to be solved is: how are you going to discover those plugins? To answer this we would need to know how do you intend to use those plugins. If should be easy if your plugins are plain old activities.

I found this post for you: http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/06/plugins.html

Comment: Oh, it would be an option to have a separate app for plugins. Thanks for the link! It talks about providing plugins as Services. I wonder would it be ok if my plugins would contain some drawing code. I.e. is it possible to load a plugin class from Service and than use this class to draw content on e.g. SurfaceView...